# How to generate all of the numbers of pi in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, ipad, nsarray

I want to create an iPad application named "Am I in Pi?" to check birthday numbers with Pi numbers and show the numbers. My question is how can I generate all of the million numbers of pi 3.1415.... etc. Is there any library in Objective-C or XML file or function that I can use for my implementation?

Comment: http://www.piday.org/million.php

Comment: 1 million digits as a text file is 1 megabyte.  Just store the text file and scan it as a text file.

Comment: Being an irrational number, you still want **all** the numbers of pi?

Comment: There's a lot more than a million digits in the decimal representation of π.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. If you need an algorithm for generating π, [Wikipedia describes several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Computer_era_and_iterative_algorithms).

Comment: Agree with @David, the number is already generated to the millions, why not just use the static file instead of generating each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than generating pi and searching for a certain sequence of digits, you're best off simply saying yes all the time. There is no evidence for any sequence *not* being in pi.

Comment: Presumably, if one is going to go to the trouble of writing an app for such a thing, the app should tell you not just YES/NO but also *where* your number occurs.

Comment: @Caleb if we're not bothering to store it/find it, I would say that it's position is somewhere around `Math.Random();`

Comment: @Caleb Your number will occur in pi exactly one infinit times. Displaying all those will likely cause the app to crash, which isn't very user friendly. I'd stick with the yes/no.

Answer (score 5):

Grab the 1 megabyte of text for pi.

Writing a script, all 1, 2, 3, and 4 digit sequences exist within this file.  Only the following 5 digit sequences don't exist within the first 1M digits of pi:

```
!!! 14523 not found
!!! 17125 not found
!!! 22801 not found
!!! 33394 not found
!!! 36173 not found
!!! 39648 not found
!!! 40527 not found
!!! 96710 not found
```

Rather than scanning the text file each time, index the location of all '#', '##', '###', '####' strings.

If you want all 5 or longer digits to be found in the string, include a larger version of the digits of pi.

Calculating the first N million digits of pi on an ipad is a waste of cpu and battery when the data file isn't that large.

Comment: This would make the question wether a so-called 'birthday number' occurs in pi a matter of having a big enough text file for any date the user chooses. This could lead to interesting stuff, though.

Comment: @timjver Big enough becomes interesting.  As I mentioned there are 8x 5 digit strings not found in the first 1M digits.  When this is extended to 6 digits, about 1/3 of the sequences are not found in the first 1M.

Comment: However, the potential user is not interested in wether the number occurs in the first n digits of pi. He's interested in wether it occurs in pi *at all*.

Comment: @timjver at all, the answer is yes.  Personally, I see him wanting an application that shows a block of numbers (the digits of pi) and saying "your birthday of 01/01 occurs at the 2563 digit: 913686722874894056*0101*5033086179286809208".  At least, that's the standard implementation of 'find your birthday in pi' type applications.

Comment: @MichaelT apparently it's still an open question as to whether pi contains all possible number strings: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations

Comment: @DavidBrown it isn't necessary to contain all possible strings.  If one is searching for a MM/DD value, that is contained within the first 1M digits. All YY/MM/DD would take probably about 3M digits (and that can be verified easily).