# find numbers in text file objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, file, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate all of the numbers of pi in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018816/how-to-generate-all-of-the-numbers-of-pi-in-objective-c)

I want to implement "am i in pi" for searching birth date in pi numbers,
I have 1 million series of pi Numbers in .txt file, would you please give me some hints for implement this game?

what is the best way? how can I found my birth date in text file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have added all pi numbers in a text file! There is no Nobel prize for math, but for this we should invent it!

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes I used this link http://www.piday.org/million.php

Comment: @ghazal: π is irrational: it has an infinite number of digits. You have the first million digits – not all of them.

Comment: @JeremyRoman yes I know I want to use this first million digits

Comment: @vikingosegundo why should I invert it would you please give me more hints

Comment: you claim to have ALL π digits. that worth the invention of a new Nobel prize for math. forget about the [Fields Medal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) — this must be a Nobel prize.

Comment: piday.org should have some funny easter egg on http://www.piday.org/all.php

Comment: @ghazal, actually your question was sufficiently answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018816/how-to-generate-all-of-the-numbers-of-pi-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: @"path to your file" encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: nil];
NSRange rng = [str rangeOfString: @"1989"]; //here is the range of the birth year 1989
```

Answer (score 0):

1 megabyte is sufficiently small that loading and then scanning it is reasonably straightforward. If you wanted to be a little clever, you could map the file into memory and then scan it through the map (avoiding the need to load the entire file into memory, which becomes more important for multi-hundred-MB files).

```
NSDataReadingOptions options = NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe | NSDataReadingUncached;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename
                                      options:options
                                        error:nil];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:year];
[string release];
```

You could add appropriate error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Once I wrote a category of NSString, which has method:

```
- (NSArray *)occurrencesOfSubstring:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, self.length);
    NSUInteger len = self.length;

    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        range = [self rangeOfString:string options:0 range:range];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSRange resRange = range;
            [result addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:resRange]];
            range = NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(resRange), len - NSMaxRange(resRange));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It returns array of ranges of searched substring. Hope it helps.